# document.write alternativ without overwriting the DOM / side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

got a problem with the usage of

> document.write()

i want to overwrite a div in which a adbanner is loaded and i cant find any solution to this.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">

<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0;
    var newImage;

    function refresh() {
        i++;
        if (i >= 5) {
            writeAd();
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    function writeAd() {

        var arr = box1.getElementsByTagName('script')
        for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++)
            eval(arr[n].innerHTML)
    }
</script>
</head>

<body
    <h1>Bilder Random</h1>
    <input type="button" onclick="refresh()" value="go!" />

    <div id="box1" class="superbanner">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="ad1">

            <script language="JavaScript">
                if (typeof (WLRCMD) == "undefined") {
                    var WLRCMD = "";
                }
                if (typeof (adlink_randomnumber) == "undefined") {
                    var adlink_randomnumber = Math
                            .floor(Math.random() * 1000000)
                }

                document
                        .write('<scr'
                                + 'ipt language="JavaScript" src="http://ad.de.doubleclick.net/adj/oms.skol.de/localnews_bilder;oms=localnews_bilder;reg=;nielsen=3b;dcopt=ist'
                                + WLRCMD + ';sz=728x90;tile=1;ord='
                                + adlink_randomnumber + '?"><\/scr'+'ipt>');
            </script>

        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My main problem is the `document.write()` in the adbanner script part.
i can reload the page with 5 clicks on the button but it overwrites the whole DOM

is there any possability to use something else than `document.write()` 
to insert the adbanner at the beginning of the page load and when calling
the `function writeAd()`?

Comment: what is the element you're trying to insert?

Comment: Did you tried [jQuery.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)?

Comment: i try to overwrite the adbanner in the div box1 with a new adbanner or more or less reload the adbanner (script) in the div

Comment: Maybe [jQuery.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/)? But not sure what you would like to achieve.

Comment: thank you for your help. im realy close to get finishing my work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should load JS files dynamically:

```
    if (window.isReady) { //after page was loaded, we must manually add new SCRIPT tag into HEAD
        var script = document.createElement('script'), head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = fileName;
        head.appendChild(script);
    }
    else { //otherwise we are still in a progress of creating HEAD or BODY and we can simply write into document
        var write = 'write'; //prevents JSlint from saying that document.write is evil ;)
        document[write]('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + fileName + '"></script>');
    }
```

To detect if window is loaded:

```
window.onload = function() { window.isReady = true; }
```